# Mapping a pointer of global variable in kernel space to user space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm trying to access a variable created in kernel space. My purpose is to detect a interrupt flag. To do that, I created a ioctl and use copy_to_user() to pass variable pointer to user as kernel code below :
- I convert virtual address of 'irq_flag' to physical address and pass to user.

```
#define GET_FLAG        _IOW('F', 0x27, int)
...    
int irq_flag = 0;      //Global variable
...
case GET_FLAG:         //IOCTL
    {
        int my_value;
        char *value_ptr;

        value_ptr = virt_to_phys(&irq_flag);
        my_value = value_ptr;
        if (copy_to_user((void __user *)arg,(void *)&my_value,
            sizeof(irq_flag)))
            return -EFAULT;
        return 0;
    }
```

User code: Get physical address from ioctl and map to virtual address

```
mem_fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
fb_fd = open("/dev/fb", O_RDWR);

int temp;
int flag_addr;
int *flag;

temp = ioctl(fb_fd, FBIOGET_FLAG, &flag_addr);
flag = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, mem_fd, flag_addr);
...//processing code
while(1){
  *flag = 0;      //my idea is that flag will be set to 1 in interrupt callback function and break the loop.
  while(!*flag) {   }
}
```

But it return Segmentation Fault, could you give me some idea where am i wrong or is it another way to map a pointer from kernel to user space. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Apart from not working, this is the wrong approach to take for a user space process to wait for something to happen in the kernel. One approach would be to call an ioctl that uses `wait_event_interruptible` to block waiting for some event to occur, and call `wake_up_interruptible` from your interrupt handler to unblock the waiter.

Comment: @IanAbbott : Maybe this is what i looking for, but it's new for me. Could you please give me some example about it? Thank you.

Comment: I suggest having a look at the [Blocking I/O](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-2.shtml) section of [Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/) to learn more about blocking and waking up in the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite one can get physical address of kernel space object and send it to user space, one can not access to kernel space from user space othervise any malware would gain full access for reading any kernel structures.

You didn't check `mmap()` return value for `MAP_FAILED` value (`(void *) -1`) and then tried to access to this invalid memory address.

Comment: You right, mmap() returned -1 because the physical address I used is not 4k alignment.